# Java 8 - java.nio.charset.MalformedInputException

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, character-encoding, stream

I am getting reading a file through java-8 and finding a match for a key in that file using the below method:

```
private static List<String> listFilesWithMatches(String[] listOfIncludedFiles, Map<String, String> myPropMapKeys) {

    List<String> mapKeyList = new ArrayList<String>(myPropMapKeys.keySet());
    List<String> matchFileList = new ArrayList<>();
    Predicate<String> p = (str) -> mapKeyList.stream().anyMatch(key -> str.contains(utf8AsLatin1(key)));



    for(String myFile : listOfIncludedFiles){
         try (Stream<String> stream = Files.lines(Paths.get(myFile))) {
             boolean foundAKey = stream.anyMatch(p);
                if(foundAKey) {
                    matchFileList.add(myFile);

                    //Listing the files that have match
                    System.out.println("**"+ROOT_PATH + File.separator + myFile);
                }
         }

         catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    System.out.println("Total Number of files with matches:: "+matchFileList.size());
    return matchFileList;
}

private static String utf8AsLatin1(String key) {
     return new String(key.getBytes(StandardCharsets.ISO_8859_1),
             StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
}
```

now i am getting the below error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.UncheckedIOException: java.nio.charset.MalformedInputException: Input length = 1
    at java.io.BufferedReader$1.hasNext(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Spliterators$IteratorSpliterator.tryAdvance(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEachWithCancel(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyIntoWithCancel(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.stream.MatchOps$MatchOp.evaluateSequential(Unknown Source)
```

The line that is creating the problem is

```
try (Stream<String> stream = Files.lines(Paths.get(myFile))) {
                 boolean foundAKey = stream.anyMatch(p);
```

Now one of the solution is to use the ISO_8859_1 charset but i want the default encoding of the file only and don't want to use any other charset. Can anybody help with this issue?

Comment: If the file you're trying to read is encoded in ISO_8859_1, you can't read it in UTF-8. There's no need to either, if you want to later write it into another file, you can do so in UTF-8 then.

Comment: You shouldn't always use ISO_8859_1 or always use UTF-8 when reading a file. You should use whatever encoding the file was written in. If the file is ISO_8859_1, then you must read it using ISO_8859_1. If you *absolutely* "want to UTF-8 only and don't want to use any other charset", then you need to **make sure *all* the files are in UTF-8**. The error is because a file is not UTF-8 and you're trying to read it as UTF-8.

Answer (score 1):

I am glad you favour UTF-8. But basically it says the file is ***not*** in UTF-8. So log the error with file path, and continue.
Manually repair the file, and resubmit it.

This might not be workable.

Alternatively use the no-fail single byte encoding ISO-8859-1,
or maybe better the default encoding of the platform:

```
Files.lines(Paths.get(myFile), StandardCharset.ISO_8859_1)

static String utf8AsLatin1(String s) {
    return new String(key.getBytes(StandardCharset.ISO_8859_1),
                      StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
}

Predicate<String> p = (str) ->
    mapKeyList.stream().anyMatch(key ->
        str.containsIgnoreCase(utf8AsLatin1(key))
        || str.containsIgnoreCase(key));
```

Theoretically using a **Charset.Decoder** with error handling would fit better. However keys could have special chars.

The above will try encoding ISO-8859-1 too. That is not enough, even for Latin European languages.

One could turn keys into regex patterns replacing special characters with a wild card sequence `.{1,6}`, and do a regex match.

**Text normalisation** is an other issue: on correctly encoded text use `java.text.Normalizer`. `à` could be one Unicode symbol (code point) or two symbols `a` and a zero-width combining diacritical mark (`).

For a search you could *decompose* the text and remove the diacritical marks. There still are some problems with Polish stroked l `ł` and Turkish dotted I `İ` and dotless i `ı`.

---

***A more sensible solution***

```
for(String myFile : listOfIncludedFiles){
     Path path = Paths.get(myFile);
     try (Stream<String> stream = Files.lines(path,
             determineCharset(path))) {


Charset determineCharset(Path path) {
    byte[] bytes = Files.readAllBytes(path);
    for (int i = 0; i < bytes.length; ++i) {
        byte b = bytes[i];
        if (b == 0) {
            return i % 2 == 0
                    ? StandardCharsets.UTF_16
                    : StandardCharsets.UTF_16LE;
        }
        if (b < 0) {
            int high1s= 0; // Length of byte sequence
            while ((b & 0x80) == 0x80) {
                ++high1s;
                b = (byte)(b << 1);
            } 
            if (high1s == 1 || i + high1s > bytes.length) {
                // A UTF-8 continuation byte
                // cannot be at the start.
                // Or not sufficient room for
                // continuation bytes
                return Charset.defaultCharset()
                    .equals(StandardCharsets.UTF_8)
                    ? StandardCharsets.ISO_8859_1
                    : Charset.defaultCharset();
            }
            int contBytes = high1s - 1;
            // Skip continuation bytes
            while (i + 1 < bytes.length
                    && (bytes[i+1] & 0b1100_0000)
                       == 0b1000_0000) {
                 ++i;
                 --contBytes;
            }
            if (contBytes != 0) {
                return Charset.defaultCharset()
                    .equals(StandardCharsets.UTF_8)
                    ? StandardCharsets.ISO_8859_1
                    : Charset.defaultCharset();
            }
        }
    }
    return StandardCharsets.UTF_8;
}
```

This checks for UTF-8 compliance (certainly can be written more nicely). When not it gives the platform encoding. When that platform encoding is UTF-8 then Latin-1.

That is a very limited solution.

Comment: Can you help me understanding how it is preserving the default encoding of the file?
this line is returning UTF-8 or IS0_8859_1
static String utf8AsLatin1(String s) {
    return new String(key.getBytes(StandardCharset.ISO_8859_1),
                      StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
And i don't want to ignore case for my key as mentioned in this line:
str.containsIgnoreCase(utf8AsLatin1(key))
        || str.containsIgnoreCase(key));

Comment: It does not change (the encoding of) the file. It is just an attempt to try two encodings: UTF-8 and ISO-8859-1 (or default would be possible too). As at least one file was not in UTF-8.

Comment: And what about this line :
str.containsIgnoreCase(utf8AsLatin1(key)) || str.containsIgnoreCase(key))
this will ignore the case sentivity and i dont want that

Comment: I have updated the code. Please have a look at it. I still facing the same issue.

Comment: I think my `new String` is flawed. Okay, I'll code a more solid solution.